# Youtube occasionally giving black screen

Tags: video, google-chrome, flash, youtube

I know that there were many questions about youtube giving blackscreen, but I went through a lot of them on none was my problem. I am using Chrome 32bit, basically, youtube sometimes stops working for me, giving a black screen in the place of the video, without any controls or anything. I tried using only Pepper flash, only adobe-flashplugin and both at the same time and it didn't work. The thing is, after some time it starts working again all by itself, without me changing pretty much anything. Which is completely bizarre, a bug that starts and stops happening all by itself, without any apparent connection to what am I doing on my computer. Also, everything else flash related works on other sites and I tried switching to HTML5 version on youtube.com/html5 with still no success.

Comment: Well, apperently watching any video on my phone solves it, making it even more bizarre and certainly Youtube-sided. Anyone got any idea why on earth is that happening?

Comment: This is still happening. I managed to guess that it's some weird Google bug happening because I am using two youtube accounts on the same Google account, but it doesn't help me solve anything. Also, the phone fix stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is turn off the hardware acceleration option in Chrome/Chromium. Settings > Advanced Settings > uncheck "use hardware acceleration when available".

Comment: I had it turned off from the very beginning. Thanks, but it turned out to be a complicated interaction between the linux flash players and Google's internal mechanism, the one that remembers what you watched etc. Switching to HTML5 player and occasional switching accounts solved the problem temporarily, and then Google fixed whatever bug was causing that.